# How do I tell apart a read error from a write error in a socket?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I am creating a server for a game that deals with lots of TCP connections, and I need to deal with a sudden loss of connection (pc crash, game process killed, internet connection lost, ectect). The problem I currently have is that I can't tell apart a read error from a write error since both throw an `IOException`. even the underlying exception is the same (`SocketException`), the only difference being that one occurs on `Socket.Send()` and the other on `Socket.Receive()` respectively. I could of course compare the exception message, but that would become a problem as soon as the system language changes (and lets be honest, that would be a pretty messy approach anyway).

I tried comparing the `Hresult` but since the underlying exception is the same, so is the `Hresult`. I also tried `getHashCode()` but this one changes from player to player.

Any other ways I could tell apart those 2 situations?
To clarify, we're talking about the exception that comes up when using `TcpClient.read()` or `TcpClient.write()` on a `TcpClient` whose connection has been unexpectedly closed.

Comment: [`TcpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) type doesn't have `read()` and `write()` functions. What is the tcp client exact type?

Comment: you could catch IOException around both the socket.send and socket.receive and rethrow another exception with more specific details or even handle the loss of connection there.

Comment: Also please note that some general errors would be found only on socket write attempt. It does not mean they are "write" errors.

Comment: @KernelMode I am using System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient , and it has a `Read()` and `Write()` method (I messed up upper/lowercase, my bad)



@ajg `Socket.Send()` and `socket.Receive()` are inside the `TcpClient` class, I don't have access to that

Comment: @LastExceed Are you talking about `NetworkStream.Read/Write`? A `NetworkStream` is accessed through `TcpClient.GetStream()`

Comment: Can you share the code that use the `Read()` and `Write()`?

Comment: @KernelMode Oh god I was stupid. It's `BinaryReader.Read()` and `BinaryWriter.Write()` ofcourse, sry. But I have a solution from another answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try wrapping the send and receive functions in a try-catch block, and use the `Data` property to tell exceptions from read and write apart:

```
enum ReadOrWrite { Read, Write }

void Foo()
{
    try
    {
        socket.Receive();
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        ex.Data.Add("readOrWrite", ReadOrWrite.Read);
        throw;
    }
}
```

And this is where you later catch it:

```
try
{
    Foo();
}
catch (IOException ex) when (ex.Data.Contains("readOrWrite"))
{
    var readOrWrite = ex.Data["readOrWrite"];
}
```

Comment: `Socket.Send()` and `socket.Receive()` are inside the `TcpClient` class, I don't have access to that

Comment: Replace it with NetworkStream.Read/Write, or whatever method you are already using to read/write data.